# Is it possible to add branch independent bookmarks in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

It seems like PhpStorm bookmarks are GIT branches related.

Is it possible to add some "global" bookmarks, witch will be available in any branch?

Comment: Will this do? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91133/Bookmarks-lost-on-branch-changes#focus=Comments-27-6539546.0-0

Comment: @LazyOne, This is not exactly what I was looking for. I don't want to disable "Restore workspace" feature, since it's really helpful. But thank you for the link, I didn't saw that thread. And, according to it's other comments, there is currently no solution to this problem. Unfortunately.